# Using MAX for all features in OPTIONS file with Flexlm licensing

Tags: flexlm

I am using OPTIONS file to limit who gets access to the licenses and how many number of licenses for each user.

I can include all features for a User or Group by using IP address wild card as per below

```
INCLUDEALL INTERNET 59.98.121.*
```

But for limiting the number of licenses I don't see any other option except MAX. 
For MAX line I don't see any option to specify all features in the license file. I have to mention one line for each feature

```
MAX 5 feature_name INTERNET 59.98.121.*
```

I have 100 groups and 500 feature, which means I will have to have 50,000 lines for MAX in the options file.

Is there a alternative way of defining the limit? Or can I exclude feature_name and it will work for all features?

Answer (score 0):

Excluding feature_name in a MAX statement is not supported by the FlexLM syntax and I have verified (on v11.16.4.0) that a MAX line without it is ignored by the system.

A solution could be to create a package with the features as components, in the license file:

```
PACKAGE package_name vendor_name COMPONENTS="feature1 feature2"
```

and then use the MAX statement with the package name (instead of the individual features) in the options file:

```
MAX 2 package_name HOST_GROUP hostgroup_name
```

This way you would have "only" 100 MAX statements to prepare.